# Python: Logging specific values to a single pandas dataframe from multiple lists with sublists

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to save specific data from my weather station to a dataframe. The code I have retrieves hourly log data as lists with sublists, and simply putting `pd.DataFrame` does not work due to multiple logs and sublists.

I am trying to make a code that retrieves specific parameters, e.g. `tempHigh` for each hourly log entry and puts it in a dataframe.
I am able to isolate the 'tempHigh' for the first hour by:

```
df = wu.hourly()["observations"][0]
x = df["metric"]
x["tempHigh"]
```

I am afraid I have to deal with my nemesis, Mr. For Loop, to retrieve each hourly log data. I was hoping to get some help on how to attack this problem most efficiently.

The screenshots show the output data structure, which continues in this structure for all hours for the past 7 days. Below I have pasted the output data for the top two log entries.

[image: Data output]

[image: Data output continued]

```
{
   "observations":[
      {
         "epoch":1607554798,
         "humidityAvg":39,
         "humidityHigh":44,
         "humidityLow":37,
         "lat":27.389829,
         "lon":33.67048,
         "metric":{
            "dewptAvg":4,
            "dewptHigh":5,
            "dewptLow":4,
            "heatindexAvg":19,
            "heatindexHigh":19,
            "heatindexLow":18,
            "precipRate":0.0,
            "precipTotal":0.0,
            "pressureMax":1017.03,
            "pressureMin":1016.53,
            "pressureTrend":0.0,
            "tempAvg":19,
            "tempHigh":19,
            "tempLow":18,
            "windchillAvg":19,
            "windchillHigh":19,
            "windchillLow":18,
            "windgustAvg":8,
            "windgustHigh":13,
            "windgustLow":2,
            "windspeedAvg":6,
            "windspeedHigh":10,
            "windspeedLow":2
         },
         "obsTimeLocal":"2020-12-10 00:59:58",
         "obsTimeUtc":"2020-12-09T22:59:58Z",
         "qcStatus":-1,
         "solarRadiationHigh":0.0,
         "stationID":"IHURGH2",
         "tz":"Africa/Cairo",
         "uvHigh":0.0,
         "winddirAvg":324
      },
      {
         "epoch":1607558398,
         "humidityAvg":48,
         "humidityHigh":52,
         "humidityLow":44,
         "lat":27.389829,
         "lon":33.67048,
         "metric":{
            "dewptAvg":7,
            "dewptHigh":8,
            "dewptLow":5,
            "heatindexAvg":18,
            "heatindexHigh":19,
            "heatindexLow":17,
            "precipRate":0.0,
            "precipTotal":0.0,
            "pressureMax":1016.93,
            "pressureMin":1016.42,
            "pressureTrend":-0.31,
            "tempAvg":18,
            "tempHigh":19,
            "tempLow":17,
            "windchillAvg":18,
            "windchillHigh":19,
            "windchillLow":17,
            "windgustAvg":10,
            "windgustHigh":15,
            "windgustLow":4,
            "windspeedAvg":8,
            "windspeedHigh":13,
            "windspeedLow":1
         },
         "obsTimeLocal":"2020-12-10 01:59:58",
         "obsTimeUtc":"2020-12-09T23:59:58Z",
         "qcStatus":-1,
         "solarRadiationHigh":0.0,
         "stationID":"IHURGH2",
         "tz":"Africa/Cairo",
         "uvHigh":0.0,
         "winddirAvg":326
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: You're missing a `}]}` in your data sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might have a solution that suits your case. The way I've tackled this challenge is to flatten the entries of the single hourly logs, so not to have a nested dictionary. With 1-dimensional dictionaries (one for each hour), easily a dataframe can be created with all the measures as columns and the date and time as index. From there on you can select whatever columns you'd like ;)

How do we get there and what do I mean by 'flatten the entries'?

The hourly logs come as single dictionaries with single key, value pairs except 'metric' which is another dictionary. What I want is to get rid of the key 'metric' but not its values. Let's look at an example:

```
# nested dictionary
original = {'a':1, 'b':2, 'foo':{'c':3}} 

# flatten original to
flattened = {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3} # got rid of key 'foo' but not its value
```

The below function achieves exactly that, a 1-dimensional or flat dictionary:

```
def flatten(dic):
    #
    update = False
    
    for key, val in dic.items():
        if isinstance(val, dict):
            update = True
            break
    
    if update: dic.update(val); dic.pop(key); flatten(dic)
    
    return dic

# With data from your weather station
hourly_log = {'epoch': 1607554798, 'humidityAvg': 39, 'humidityHigh': 44, 'humidityLow': 37, 'lat': 27.389829, 'lon': 33.67048, 'metric': {'dewptAvg': 4, 'dewptHigh': 5, 'dewptLow': 4, 'heatindexAvg': 19, 'heatindexHigh': 19, 'heatindexLow': 18, 'precipRate': 0.0, 'precipTotal': 0.0, 'pressureMax': 1017.03, 'pressureMin': 1016.53, 'pressureTrend': 0.0, 'tempAvg': 19, 'tempHigh': 19, 'tempLow': 18, 'windchillAvg': 19, 'windchillHigh': 19, 'windchillLow': 18, 'windgustAvg': 8, 'windgustHigh': 13, 'windgustLow': 2, 'windspeedAvg': 6, 'windspeedHigh': 10, 'windspeedLow': 2}, 'obsTimeLocal': '2020-12-10 00:59:58', 'obsTimeUtc': '2020-12-09T22:59:58Z', 'qcStatus': -1, 'solarRadiationHigh': 0.0, 'stationID': 'IHURGH2', 'tz': 'Africa/Cairo', 'uvHigh': 0.0, 'winddirAvg': 324}
# Flatten with function
flatten(hourly_log)
>>> {'epoch': 1607554798,
     'humidityAvg': 39,
     'humidityHigh': 44,
     'humidityLow': 37,
     'lat': 27.389829,
     'lon': 33.67048,
     'obsTimeLocal': '2020-12-10 00:59:58',
     'obsTimeUtc': '2020-12-09T22:59:58Z',
     'qcStatus': -1,
     'solarRadiationHigh': 0.0,
     'stationID': 'IHURGH2',
     'tz': 'Africa/Cairo',
     'uvHigh': 0.0,
     'winddirAvg': 324,
     'dewptAvg': 4,
     'dewptHigh': 5,
     'dewptLow': 4,
     'heatindexAvg': 19,
     'heatindexHigh': 19,
     'heatindexLow': 18,
     'precipRate': 0.0,
     'precipTotal': 0.0,
     'pressureMax': 1017.03,
     'pressureMin': 1016.53,
     'pressureTrend': 0.0, 
      ...
```

**Notice**: 'metric' is gone but not its values!

Now, a DataFrame can be easily created for each hourly log which can be concatenated to a single DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd

hourly_logs = wu.hourly()['observations']

# List of DataFrames for each hour
frames = [pd.DataFrame(flatten(dic), index=[0]).set_index('epoch') for dic in hourly_logs]

# Concatenated to a single one
df = pd.concat(frames)

# With adjusted index as Date and Time
dti = pd.DatetimeIndex(df.index * 10**9)
df.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([dti.date, dti.time])

# All measures
df.columns
>>> Index(['humidityAvg', 'humidityHigh', 'humidityLow', 'lat', 'lon',
       'obsTimeLocal', 'obsTimeUtc', 'qcStatus', 'solarRadiationHigh',
       'stationID', 'tz', 'uvHigh', 'winddirAvg', 'dewptAvg', 'dewptHigh',
       'dewptLow', 'heatindexAvg', 'heatindexHigh', 'heatindexLow',
       'precipRate', 'precipTotal', 'pressureMax', 'pressureMin',
       'pressureTrend', 'tempAvg', 'tempHigh', 'tempLow', 'windchillAvg',
       'windchillHigh', 'windchillLow', 'windgustAvg', 'windgustHigh',
       'windgustLow', 'windspeedAvg', 'windspeedHigh', 'windspeedLow'],
      dtype='object')

# Read out specific measures
df[['tempHigh','tempLow','tempAvg']]
>>>
```

[image: Specific measures]

Hopefully this is what you've been looking for!

Answer (score 1):

Pandas accepts a list of dictionaries as input to create a [dataframe](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html):

```
import pandas as pd

input_dict = {"observations":[
    {
        "epoch":1607554798,
         "humidityAvg":39,
         "humidityHigh":44,
         "humidityLow":37,
         "lat":27.389829,
         "lon":33.67048,
         "metric":{
             "dewptAvg":4,
             "dewptHigh":5,
             "dewptLow":4,
             "heatindexAvg":19,
             "heatindexHigh":19,
             "heatindexLow":18,
             "precipRate":0.0,
             "precipTotal":0.0,
             "pressureMax":1017.03,
             "pressureMin":1016.53,
             "pressureTrend":0.0,
             "tempAvg":19,
             "tempHigh":19,
             "tempLow":18,
             "windchillAvg":19,
             "windchillHigh":19,
             "windchillLow":18,
             "windgustAvg":8,
             "windgustHigh":13,
             "windgustLow":2,
             "windspeedAvg":6,
             "windspeedHigh":10,
             "windspeedLow":2
          },
          "obsTimeLocal":"2020-12-10 00:59:58",
          "obsTimeUtc":"2020-12-09T22:59:58Z",
          "qcStatus":-1,
          "solarRadiationHigh":0.0,
          "stationID":"IHURGH2",
          "tz":"Africa/Cairo",
          "uvHigh":0.0,
          "winddirAvg":324
       },
       {
          "epoch":1607558398,
          "humidityAvg":48,
          "humidityHigh":52,
          "humidityLow":44,
          "lat":27.389829,
          "lon":33.67048,
          "metric":{
              "dewptAvg":7,
              "dewptHigh":8,
              "dewptLow":5,
              "heatindexAvg":18,
              "heatindexHigh":19,
              "heatindexLow":17,
              "precipRate":0.0,
              "precipTotal":0.0,
              "pressureMax":1016.93,
              "pressureMin":1016.42,
              "pressureTrend":-0.31,
              "tempAvg":18,
              "tempHigh":19,
              "tempLow":17,
              "windchillAvg":18,
              "windchillHigh":19,
              "windchillLow":17,
              "windgustAvg":10,
              "windgustHigh":15,
              "windgustLow":4,
              "windspeedAvg":8,
              "windspeedHigh":13,
              "windspeedLow":1
           },
           "obsTimeLocal":"2020-12-10 01:59:58",
           "obsTimeUtc":"2020-12-09T23:59:58Z",
           "qcStatus":-1,
           "solarRadiationHigh":0.0,
           "stationID":"IHURGH2",
           "tz":"Africa/Cairo",
           "uvHigh":0.0,
           "winddirAvg":326
          }
     ]
}

observations = input_dict["observations"]
df = pd.DataFrame(observations)
```

If you now want a list of single "metrics" you need to "flatten" your list of dictionaries column. This does use your "Nemesis" but in a Pythonic way:

```
temperature_high = [d.get("tempHigh") for d in df["metric"].to_list()]
```

If you want all the metrics in a dataframe, even simpler, just get the list of dictionaries from the specific column:

```
metrics = pd.DataFrame(df["metric"].to_list())
```

As you would probably like the timestamp as an index to denote your entries (your rows), you can pick your column `epoch`, or the more *human* `obsTimeLocal`:

```
metrics = pd.DataFrame(df["metric"].to_list(), index=df["obsTimeLocal"].to_list())
```

From here you can read specific metrics of your interest:

```
metrics[["tempHigh", "tempLow"]]
```

[image: Dataframe screenshot generated with Jupyter notebooks]